# Is there any alternative for WHERE NOT IN(..)?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers_cards
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT card_id FROM customers_card_psp)
```

It takes about 2sec to get executed and we need this query to get called on a highly visited page.  Any idea how can I make it more optimize?

Here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

Noted that `card_id` is not unique (there are 5 rows inside `customers_card_psp` per 1 row inside `customers_cards`), but adding `DISTINCT` in the behind of `card_id` doesn't make anything better.

---

Noted that, using `LEFT JOIN` has the same performance:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM customers_cards cc
LEFT JOIN customers_card_psp ccp ON ccp.card_id = cc.id
WHERE ccp.id IS null
```

[image]

Comment: what is this request supposed to do? of course it's taking a lot of time, you're querying over a table that has 1.2M rows!

Comment: @Gugu72 I'm trying to find Cards that are not added inside PSPs to retry adding them.

Comment: can you add created indexes for both tables in your question?

Comment: @Gugu72 Both `cc.id` and `ccp.id` are PK, also there is an index on `ccp.card_id`

Comment: You don't tend to optimize any code these days by just having drop in replacements asking for the same logical result but in a different way - those sort of hand optimizations were common enough a few decades ago but these days, we expect compilers and query optimizers to be able to perform such *mechanical* transformations themselves. *Indexes* are the major tool for optimizing queries.

Comment: it is definitely supposed to be using cc.id PK here, are you sure it is well defined as a PK?

Comment: Yes @Gugu72 .. I'm sure about that

Comment: hmm, what about if you add `USE INDEX (PRIMARY)` in your query? ie `SELECT * FROM customer_cards USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE ...`. (replace PRIMARY with the cc.id index name, but keep parenthesis). does it take more time? what does the EXPLAIN of that query gives?

Comment: Tried, same result @Gugu72

Comment: what about `FORCE INDEX`? it seems that the optimizer finds it faster to do a full table scan than use the index, this will force it to use the index so that we can see what's the difference

Comment: I tried using `FORCE` instead of `USE`, but still the *type* is `ALL` and `1124338` rows will be scanned.

Comment: this is strange, I'm sorry but I can't help any further :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254539/discussion-between-gugu72-and-martin-aj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 3 ways to say the same thing:

```
SELECT *
    FROM customers_cards
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT card_id FROM customers_card_psp )
```

vs

```
SELECT *
    FROM customers_cards AS cc
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1               -- anything works here; "1" is the convention
            FROM customers_card_psp
            WHERE card_id = cc.id )
```

vs

```
SELECT cc.*
    FROM customers_cards AS cc
    LEFT JOIN customers_card_psp AS psp
           ON psp.card_id = cc.id       -- How the tables 'relate'
    WHERE psp.card_id IS NULL           -- Means "missing from psp"
```

The `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` is notoriously inefficient and should be avoided.

The `EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN` are probably compiled identically, hence equally good.

The `EXISTS` is called "semi-join" meaning that it only needs to find 0 or 1 row, not all 5, in order to satisfy the test.

Related: The comparisons are probably the same without the `NOT` (and changing to `IS NULL`).  That is, do not use `IN`; use either of the others.

(Different versions of MySQL/MariaDB have optimized these things differently.)

Answer (score 1):

> It takes about 2sec to get executed and we need this query to get called on a highly visited page.

As presented, this query needs to read EVERY SINGLE ROW in customer_cards. Hence either:

1. Your "highly visited page" is displaying hundreds of thousands of rows
2. there are other filtering predicates you've not told us about
3. most of the records in customer_cards are excluded from the result set on the grounds of having corresponding records in customer_car_psp

For scenario 1 this is bad UX design - which you can't fix in your database. But if really is the right way to solve the problem, consider caching outside the DBMS.

For scenario 2 we can't help you tune a query you have not shown us (nor have you included the schema)

For scenario 3 you need to redesign your table structure